# Parse This or This Using Regex

Tags: regex, parsing

I simply can't figure this out and have been trying for awhile.  I need a regex that will parse data in the following manner:

Lets say I've got an input in the following format:

```
www.google.com
www.google.com/
www.google.com/something
```

I need a regex that will parse the above three URLs (individually) to final result of:

```
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
```

However, the way it needs to match them, is based on the following:

```
Parse and return everything to the left of a "/" if one exists in the line
Parse and return the entire line if no "/" exists in the line
```

I'm new to regex, so while this may be simple, I can't figure it out.

Comment: When you say "left of a /", do you mean the first or last "/"?

Comment: What engine/language of regex are you using?

Comment: fge - There will only ever be one "/" in each line (if there is one at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
[^/]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Substiture `/.*` with nothing. It doesn't matter if there isn't a / at all since in this case the regex will not match.